# HTTP PUT, DELETE and I/O streams with PHP

Tags: php, http, put, http-delete

Is there any way I can access data that was sent via HTTP PUT method other than `$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");`?

I have never worked with `PUT` and `DELETE` methods and `$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");` seems a bit sketchy. Will it work everywhere is a specific server/php.ini configuration required?

I know that I can get the request method from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`

But will the data be in `$_REQUEST`, if yes then what `php://input` is about? 
And how do I access data that was sent via `DELETE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to parse the request manually. `$_REQUEST` only contains data coming from `GET` and `POST` requests; for everything else you are on your own.

If your HTTP request has `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you can parse it back into a variables array very easily with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) like this:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $vars);
print_r($vars);
```

You can use this content type with any HTTP method, there is no standard-imposed limitation.

Comment: Interesting! And 'DELETE' will also be in `php://input`?

Comment: @rinchik: `php://input` contains whatever the client sent as the body of the HTTP request. The method (GET/POST/DELETE/whatever) is also the client's choice. The type of data sent as the body is also the client's choice. So yes, it will work for everything *as long as the server knows how to process what the client sent*. My example illustrates only one possible way of doing things, chosen because it's exactly the same as what's used when a form is submitted with POST.

Comment: oh! just found this: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body-stream.php alternative to `file_get_contents('php://input'), $vars`

Comment: @rinchik: I don't see the point in using a function from an extension you have to install manually instead of a built-in that does the same job.